# Visual studio 2010 first chance exception KernelBase.dll : 0x000006BA: Win32 exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am getting this on a build right after the line that says this:
Loaded 'c:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information striped).

That is the last thing I see when the program DOES NOT open in debug.

When it DOES open in debug I get the following after that line:
First-chance exception at 0x75f0c42d (KernelBase.dll) in xxx.exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable.

Most of the time I get the first case so I have to keep stopping the debug and starting it until the program comes up with the 2 case.

I have tried setting a break point for that exception from info I found on here already but even if i comment it out, i still get the first case with no program opening for debug.

I have tried using Microsoft Symbol Servers and without.

I am not sure what else to try as I am only getting the program running about 1 tries in 6.

Comment: We might need your code to be able to help you with this. Try creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to share with us.

Comment: This is a full and very large program owned by the company I work for , sorry , can't share the whole thing. Let me know if there is anything else i can provide or try. thanks.

Comment: The "whole thing" wouldn't be *minimal*. Debugging by trying isolate the problem and writing just enough code to make it happen is a great way of troubleshooting. You might even solve the problem yourself in the process .

Comment: I tend to believe differently in that a small program will probably not have this problem. I could test and see though. After doing Windows most recent updates the problem seems to have gone away. I was able to run the program three times in a row.